# In Linux, how to temporarly freeze a user?

Tags: linux, nfs, process, suspend

On a mis-configured or buggy network filer (NFS NAS) writing a large file can cause the filer to freeze.

For diagnostics I need to be able to:

1. Suspend (or in other words temporary freeze) all processes of a particular user
2. Resume the user

Basically, like a `kill -s SIGSTOP` and `kill -s SIGCONT` but for the entire user.

To do that, is there a way to temporary take away all CPU-time from a user in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this more reliably than SIGSTOP and SIGCONT by using the [cgroup freezer](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/freezer-subsystem.txt).

Comment: I'm going to give it a try. Looks like I just have to echo pid of all running processes of the user into /tasks. It's a bit annoying that if the user tries to open another SSH connection then new processes will not be added to the cgroup.

Comment: I could not try it. I have 2.6.36 openvz kernel for some reason I don't have the cgroup fs type when I try to do `mount -t cgroup -ofreezer freezer  /containers` but I seems to work on Ubunut 11.04 (Linux 2.6.38)

Answer (score 0):

Try `pkill -STOP -u <username>` and resume with `pkill -CONT -u <username>`

Comment: This could cause problems depending on order in which pkill sends the signals. For example, suspending a child process before the parent will cause bash for-loops to break. Also, what if the user already had some processes suspended (e.g. Ctrl-Z)?